# Save Workflow as template does not work in SP Designer

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, workflow

I have a workflow in SP2013 on prem that I want to export/move to another site SP Online)

In SP Designer have tried to select the workflow and select "Export as template" in the Ribbon. It "seems" to work and I get the message

> "The template has been saved to Site Assets".

But the Site Assets-folder is empty!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be aware of The Workflow Template is not shown **directly** in `Site Asset` within the SharePoint Designer, you should click on the **refresh** button to can see it.

[image]

Meanwhile, if you opened the `Site Asset` library from the web, you should find the saved templated.

---

**Note:**

> The Workflow Template should be saved to the `Site Asset` of the same
>   site.
>
> **For example**, If you have `saved a workflow as a template` in a sub site, you should find your **workflow.wsp** file in its `Site Asset`
>   libray, not at the Site collection Site Asset.

Comment: You are correct, I didnt notice that reload-button. Thanks!